# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new in Spring and Hibernate

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xv/profilemanager/exceptions/InvalidPasswordException
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:543)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>       at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: xv/profilemanager/exceptions/InvalidPasswordException
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
>       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector.selectMethods(HandlerMethodSelector.java:57)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:149)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>       ... 34 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: xv.profilemanager.exceptions.InvalidPasswordException
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
>       ... 46 more

my InvalidPasswordException class is as follows

```
package xv.profilemanager.exceptions;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

/**
 * This exception will come when password will not follow all the rules 
 * @author Pankaj Goyal
 *
 */

public cl
```

ass InvalidPasswordException extends Exception {

```
public InvalidPasswordException() {

}

public InvalidPasswordException(String message) {

    super(message);

}

public InvalidPasswordException(String message, Throwable cause) {

    super(message, cause);

}

}
```

in my configuration file I have added

please if anybody knows then reply. 
**Note** : Exception class and controller class is different projects.

Comment: do you have this class in application classpath?

Comment: Yes I am using this class in my code and I am using import statement there. That is working fine. There is no compilation problem.

Comment: no. my question is about classpath during application start. see startup command in logs or in console: java -classpath ??? test.app.Main

Comment: From your error trace,I think you are using spring mvc as well.Please remove your exception class from the package where you defined your controllers.And also check whether the particular class present inside of your war package.